# How can I fix my grouping and legend in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm really new to R and i'm trying to group the x axis together instead it being separate like it it and also move the legend.

[Graph and Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhy1r.png) http://127.0.0.1:41763/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=1200&height=455

```
Ran<-table(data$class, data$feeling)
Raw<-barplot(Ran, main="Class Feeling",xlab="Feeling", col=c("darkblue","red"), legend = rownames(Ran), beside=TRUE)
```

I would help with moving the legend and have the x-axis grouped as one. on the group its two separate, like Great and Great, where i just want one great on the group with the data together by the different times

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify legend position and others by using `args.legend()`. Unfortunately I can't tell you exactly what to do without knowing what data set would looks. However, I think [this page](https://coders-corner.net/2016/03/06/data-visualization-in-r-show-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area/) might help you.